# Minimum Height for Fixed Footer - I USED @media

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu and footer with a **position:fixed;**, so they stay all the time at the top and bottom.

In this case Menu is always at the top and footer always at the bottom.

Here is the HTML Markup and CSS

**PLEASE READ BELOW TO SEE WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE AND TO SEE UPDATE.**

**** **ORIGINAL POST** ****

```css
html, body {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

nav, footer {
 position:fixed;
 background:#900;
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
}

nav {
 top:0;
}

footer {
 bottom:0;
}

p {
 background: #E6E6E6;
 margin:0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fixed Footer</title>

</head>

<body>

<nav>Top Fixed Menu</nav>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ut libero in est dictum rutrum eu in nibh. Etiam tincidunt neque ante, eu efficitur velit semper sed. Ut lobortis et felis vitae aliquet. Nulla tincidunt leo vitae elit posuere, eu fermentum metus dictum. Praesent tincidunt egestas massa. Cras iaculis aliquam malesuada. Pellentesque at turpis diam. Vestibulum turpis augue, pulvinar et augue quis, venenatis dapibus dui. Nunc sollicitudin porta mauris, vel gravida erat placerat a.</p>
 
 
<p>Vivamus facilisis orci nec leo ultrices tristique. Donec euismod tincidunt luctus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer congue mattis convallis. Curabitur in dictum nisi, lacinia porta lectus.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo imperdiet scelerisque. Mauris vitae erat ut enim imperdiet pulvinar a vitae augue. Pellentesque non sem ipsum. Nam id quam metus. Aliquam nulla ipsum, ullamcorper vel est vitae, euismod feugiat massa. Nullam molestie, odio sollicitudin egestas laoreet, elit tortor pharetra arcu, consectetur dignissim quam libero in augue. Suspendisse augue diam, condimentum nec sagittis ac, rutrum sit amet orci. Nulla facilisi. Cras finibus lorem diam. In non tortor ut urna lobortis fermentum. Maecenas a orci odio. Aenean turpis enim, tincidunt nec mi non, dapibus iaculis diam. Vivamus eleifend velit id nulla eleifend gravida.</p>

<p>Sed rutrum dui non dui rhoncus tristique. Nulla in enim est. Sed sollicitudin pharetra risus ut vestibulum. Sed sed cursus magna, non imperdiet turpis. Praesent gravida lacinia congue. In non neque sed nulla fermentum eleifend gravida ac sem. In eget molestie velit. Suspendisse bibendum nec eros id dapibus. Quisque sagittis a ante in mollis.</p> 

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ut libero in est dictum rutrum eu in nibh. Etiam tincidunt neque ante, eu efficitur velit semper sed. Ut lobortis et felis vitae aliquet. Nulla tincidunt leo vitae elit posuere, eu fermentum metus dictum. Praesent tincidunt egestas massa. Cras iaculis aliquam malesuada. Pellentesque at turpis diam. Vestibulum turpis augue, pulvinar et augue quis, venenatis dapibus dui. Nunc sollicitudin porta mauris, vel gravida erat placerat a.</p>
 
 
<p>Vivamus facilisis orci nec leo ultrices tristique. Donec euismod tincidunt luctus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer congue mattis convallis. Curabitur in dictum nisi, lacinia porta lectus.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo imperdiet scelerisque. Mauris vitae erat ut enim imperdiet pulvinar a vitae augue. Pellentesque non sem ipsum. Nam id quam metus. Aliquam nulla ipsum, ullamcorper vel est vitae, euismod feugiat massa. Nullam molestie, odio sollicitudin egestas laoreet, elit tortor pharetra arcu, consectetur dignissim quam libero in augue. Suspendisse augue diam, condimentum nec sagittis ac, rutrum sit amet orci. Nulla facilisi. Cras finibus lorem diam. In non tortor ut urna lobortis fermentum. Maecenas a orci odio. Aenean turpis enim, tincidunt nec mi non, dapibus iaculis diam. Vivamus eleifend velit id nulla eleifend gravida.</p>

<p>Sed rutrum dui non dui rhoncus tristique. Nulla in enim est. Sed sollicitudin pharetra risus ut vestibulum. Sed sed cursus magna, non imperdiet turpis. Praesent gravida lacinia congue. In non neque sed nulla fermentum eleifend gravida ac sem. In eget molestie velit. Suspendisse bibendum nec eros id dapibus. Quisque sagittis a ante in mollis.</p> 

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ut libero in est dictum rutrum eu in nibh. Etiam tincidunt neque ante, eu efficitur velit semper sed. Ut lobortis et felis vitae aliquet. Nulla tincidunt leo vitae elit posuere, eu fermentum metus dictum. Praesent tincidunt egestas massa. Cras iaculis aliquam malesuada. Pellentesque at turpis diam. Vestibulum turpis augue, pulvinar et augue quis, venenatis dapibus dui. Nunc sollicitudin porta mauris, vel gravida erat placerat a.</p>
 
 
<p>Vivamus facilisis orci nec leo ultrices tristique. Donec euismod tincidunt luctus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer congue mattis convallis. Curabitur in dictum nisi, lacinia porta lectus.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo imperdiet scelerisque. Mauris vitae erat ut enim imperdiet pulvinar a vitae augue. Pellentesque non sem ipsum. Nam id quam metus. Aliquam nulla ipsum, ullamcorper vel est vitae, euismod feugiat massa. Nullam molestie, odio sollicitudin egestas laoreet, elit tortor pharetra arcu, consectetur dignissim quam libero in augue. Suspendisse augue diam, condimentum nec sagittis ac, rutrum sit amet orci. Nulla facilisi. Cras finibus lorem diam. In non tortor ut urna lobortis fermentum. Maecenas a orci odio. Aenean turpis enim, tincidunt nec mi non, dapibus iaculis diam. Vivamus eleifend velit id nulla eleifend gravida.</p>

<p>Sed rutrum dui non dui rhoncus tristique. Nulla in enim est. Sed sollicitudin pharetra risus ut vestibulum. Sed sed cursus magna, non imperdiet turpis. Praesent gravida lacinia congue. In non neque sed nulla fermentum eleifend gravida ac sem. In eget molestie velit. Suspendisse bibendum nec eros id dapibus. Quisque sagittis a ante in mollis.</p> 

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ut libero in est dictum rutrum eu in nibh. Etiam tincidunt neque ante, eu efficitur velit semper sed. Ut lobortis et felis vitae aliquet. Nulla tincidunt leo vitae elit posuere, eu fermentum metus dictum. Praesent tincidunt egestas massa. Cras iaculis aliquam malesuada. Pellentesque at turpis diam. Vestibulum turpis augue, pulvinar et augue quis, venenatis dapibus dui. Nunc sollicitudin porta mauris, vel gravida erat placerat a.</p>
 
 
<p>Vivamus facilisis orci nec leo ultrices tristique. Donec euismod tincidunt luctus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer congue mattis convallis. Curabitur in dictum nisi, lacinia porta lectus.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo imperdiet scelerisque. Mauris vitae erat ut enim imperdiet pulvinar a vitae augue. Pellentesque non sem ipsum. Nam id quam metus. Aliquam nulla ipsum, ullamcorper vel est vitae, euismod feugiat massa. Nullam molestie, odio sollicitudin egestas laoreet, elit tortor pharetra arcu, consectetur dignissim quam libero in augue. Suspendisse augue diam, condimentum nec sagittis ac, rutrum sit amet orci. Nulla facilisi. Cras finibus lorem diam. In non tortor ut urna lobortis fermentum. Maecenas a orci odio. Aenean turpis enim, tincidunt nec mi non, dapibus iaculis diam. Vivamus eleifend velit id nulla eleifend gravida.</p>

<p>Sed rutrum dui non dui rhoncus tristique. Nulla in enim est. Sed sollicitudin pharetra risus ut vestibulum. Sed sed cursus magna, non imperdiet turpis. Praesent gravida lacinia congue. In non neque sed nulla fermentum eleifend gravida ac sem. In eget molestie velit. Suspendisse bibendum nec eros id dapibus. Quisque sagittis a ante in mollis.</p> 

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ut libero in est dictum rutrum eu in nibh. Etiam tincidunt neque ante, eu efficitur velit semper sed. Ut lobortis et felis vitae aliquet. Nulla tincidunt leo vitae elit posuere, eu fermentum metus dictum. Praesent tincidunt egestas massa. Cras iaculis aliquam malesuada. Pellentesque at turpis diam. Vestibulum turpis augue, pulvinar et augue quis, venenatis dapibus dui. Nunc sollicitudin porta mauris, vel gravida erat placerat a.</p>
 
 
<p>Vivamus facilisis orci nec leo ultrices tristique. Donec euismod tincidunt luctus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer congue mattis convallis. Curabitur in dictum nisi, lacinia porta lectus.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo imperdiet scelerisque. Mauris vitae erat ut enim imperdiet pulvinar a vitae augue. Pellentesque non sem ipsum. Nam id quam metus. Aliquam nulla ipsum, ullamcorper vel est vitae, euismod feugiat massa. Nullam molestie, odio sollicitudin egestas laoreet, elit tortor pharetra arcu, consectetur dignissim quam libero in augue. Suspendisse augue diam, condimentum nec sagittis ac, rutrum sit amet orci. Nulla facilisi. Cras finibus lorem diam. In non tortor ut urna lobortis fermentum. Maecenas a orci odio. Aenean turpis enim, tincidunt nec mi non, dapibus iaculis diam. Vivamus eleifend velit id nulla eleifend gravida.</p>

<p>Sed rutrum dui non dui rhoncus tristique. Nulla in enim est. Sed sollicitudin pharetra risus ut vestibulum. Sed sed cursus magna, non imperdiet turpis. Praesent gravida lacinia congue. In non neque sed nulla fermentum eleifend gravida ac sem. In eget molestie velit. Suspendisse bibendum nec eros id dapibus. Quisque sagittis a ante in mollis.</p> 

<footer>Bottom Fixed Footer</footer>



</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that if viewport goes below 300px in height the distance between the Top Menu and the Footer is always 500px.

But if viewport goes beyond 500px in height, the Top Menu and Footer stay fixed at the top and the bottom and the space between them increases as long as the viewport keeps increasing.

How I can achieve this?

The content flow when scrolling if anyone wonders.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**** **UPDATED** ****

I end up using @media for that specific height I did not want the footer to be fixed when viewport was below 500 px height.

Originally I had this

```
nav, footer {
    position:fixed;
    background:#900;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
}
```

I just added this add media when the viewport goes below 500px height.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 499px) {
footer {
    position:relative;
}
}
```

I also added this inside the HEAD element to make the @media work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: If the height of the viewport is less than 500px, what should happen if the content requires more height than that?

Answer (score 0):

If the viewport is <500px, limit the displayed area to the height minus the header, while keeping the footer at the bottom. If it is >500px, also keep the footer at the bottom.
This should work:

```js
function addmore() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = '<p>'+i+': some page content</p>' + document.getElementById('a').innerHTML;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
nav,
footer {
  flex: 0;
  background: red;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
@media screen and (max-height: 499px) {
  .content {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>nav bar</nav>
  <main>
    <section class="content">
      <button onclick="addmore()">add more</button>
      <p id="a">some page content</p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: This does not works, it does not keep the footer on a fixed position at the bottom if viewport goes beyond 500px height.

Comment: I've given the `body` the `min-height: 500px + [header height + footer height]` instead of having the main viewport with the min-height, and it should work now.

Comment: I have given min-height: 500px; to BODY and to NAV and FOOTER height: 50px; but does not work yet, did you make it work?

Comment: The snippet in my answer seems to work, unless I am misunderstanding what you want. All of the paragraphs in your example would go inside the `.content` section in my answer.

Comment: If you add more content in your snippet and the content goes beyond the 500px mark in height, then the footer should stay position fixed at the bottom but your snippet does NOT do that because the more content I add the footer keeps moving down and loses the fixed position.

Comment: It works without content but not when I add more content

Comment: and yes I am adding content inside the section with class .content

Comment: Edited again so that footer is always visible and does not move down with content.

Comment: It got close to what I am looking for, I think I will be using that @media instead. Thanks